# sampling - restricting the number of times each element gets used

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to sample numbers 1:40, 3812 times (length = 3812), with replacement - but restrict it such that each number doesn't get used more than 100 times. 
Is there a way to build this type of restriction in the sampling command (`sample()`)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option:

```
sample(rep(1:40, 100), 3812)
```

Essentially, you start by building a vector of all possible numbers to sample from (`rep(1:40, 100)`), i.e. each number occurs as often as the *maximum* number of times it should be sampled (100) and then sample from it *without* replacement.

Comment: Thank you! Makes total sense :)